# Which insserv tags do I have to add to initrd-tools.sh?

Tags: init.d

I have installed insserv on my debian 7 server.

When I call `insserv` I get the error

```
insserv: warning: script 'S19initrd-tools.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

which means, that the tags in my init.d script are missing. Now that script doesn't need any tags on its call, so what would be the correct header for insserv?

I found this [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/initscripts-ng-commits@lists.alioth.debian.org/msg00728.html):

```
==============================================================================
--- trunk/src/insserv/debian/overrides/initrd-tools.sh (added)
+++ trunk/src/insserv/debian/overrides/initrd-tools.sh Sun Jul 27 12:19:51 2008
@@ -1,0 +1,7 @@
+### BEGIN INIT INFO
+# Provides:          initrd-tools
+# Required-Start:    mountdevsubfs
+# Required-Stop: 
+# Default-Start:     S
+# Default-Stop:
+### END INIT INFO
```

would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the top (after the first line `#!/bin/sh`):

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          initrd-tools
# Required-Start:    mountdevsubfs
# Required-Stop: 
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:
### END INIT INFO
```

and the message will be gone